# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter

when I upgrade my flutter to 2.0.1, shows this error:

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

this is my code:

```
  enum SubStatus {
  SUB,
  UNSUB,
}

extension ResponseStatusExtension on SubStatus{
  static const statusCodes = {
    SubStatus.SUB: "sub",
    SubStatus.UNSUB: "unsub",
  };

  String? get statusCode => statusCodes[this];
}
```

This is how to use it:

String url = "/post/sub/source/" +  subStatus.statusCode + "/" + channelId;

this is the error UI:

[image]

what should I do to fix it? I tried to return `String` but in the enum code tell me should return `String?`:

[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type of `statusCode` to `String` and provide a default value.

```dart
String get statusCode => statusCodes[this] ?? '';
```

When accessing a map, there is a chance that you will get a `null` return value if the key does not exist in the map. Simply providing a default value will allow this code to compile. That default value should never be used unless you add something to the enum without adding a value to the map as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
After the comment from @Christopher Moore, I realized my mistake. So, I am going to directly use his solution over here as it is the correct one.
This is because of the new null-safety feature of Dart.

You will need to make the following change in the code and it will work:

```dart
String get statusCode => statusCodes[this] ?? '';
```

With new null-safety rules, the following `data-type? x`, the data type is followed by a question mark, means that the value `x` can be null. However, without the '?', it means that `data-type x`, it cannot be null.

So, basically `String` and `String?` are two different data types. That is why you get the error.

You can learn more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety).

Comment: While the premise of this answer is correct, there was a reason the OP had a nullable return type. When assessing the `statusCodes` map, there is a possibility of returning `null` in the eyes of the compiler. They need to do a null check and provide a default value if they expect to return the non-nullable `String`. So the code you provide will not compile under null-safety.

Comment: but at this line tell me return String? ====> `String get statusCode => statusCodes[this];`@Preet Shah

Comment: Yes, I agree with it @ChristopherMoore. After your comment, I searched for a bit and found this article on Medium that helps me understand enum extensions. I will make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

restart analysis server

add `!`
like this
`subStatus.statusCode!`

Comment: Why is it necessary to restart the analysis server?

Comment: perhaps some changes in analyser having some issues after null safety

Comment: Perhaps, but that's unlikely when there are clear issues elsewhere that would lead static analysis to show an error as expected.

Comment: may be u can try strong mode it will show error more frequently